# How to use the `:=` operator in an R package?

Tags: r, package

I'm wondering how to accurately use the following command in an R package:

```r
command <- "a + b"
dep <- "variable"

dplyr::tibble(a = rnorm(100),
              b = rnorm(100)) -> test

test %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(!!dep := eval(parse(text = command)))

# A tibble: 100 × 3
a         b          variable
<dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
  1 -0.940  -0.177    -1.12  
2  0.0340  1.03      1.07  
3  1.00    0.549     1.55  
4 -0.995  -2.60     -3.60  
5 -1.34    1.27     -0.0660
6 -0.315   0.00188  -0.313 
7 -1.30    2.27      0.966 
8 -1.22    0.682    -0.534 
9 -1.71    1.28     -0.427 
10 -0.407  -1.48     -1.89  
# … with 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

But when running the R CMD checks, I obviously get the problem that there is no function definition for `:=`:

`no visible global function definition for ':='`

Any ideas how I can properly define this in a package? I already looked at the `glue` package and this:

```
rlang::`dyn-dots`
```

But I can't seem to find a good way of dealing with this. Any ideas? Also happy to consider a work-around on the above that does not use the operator.

Comment: You may try `#' @importFrom rlang :=`

Comment: akrun's right, and make sure you update `NAMESPACE`, and have `rlang` in the `Imports:` section of your package `DESCRIPTION` (or CMD check will complain).

Comment: Excellent, many thanks to you both - this worked! If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: You don't need a real definition for it, because it is never used.  Just define something like ` ':=' <- function(x, y) stop(":= used out of context")` which is more or less what `rlang` does.

Answer (score -1):

The ':=' is a part of **data.table** package. To use this operator you need to load the **data.table** package in R. For example, in your example code, the := operator assigns **dep** to **variable** in a new column in your **test** dataset after unquoting your command and converting it to formula and applying it to test data saving the results of formula into **variable** column. Also probably you need to convert your test data to data.table format.

Hope it could helps

Comment: Thanks SALAR, in this case I'm referring to the := operator from the rlang package. Would the example above also work with assigning the := operator from the data.table package?

Comment: @MoritzSchwarz Yes, it would also work for the ‘data.table’ package.